# Adding third endpoint in the web.config showing error

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

am first time using WCF Service and when i add 2 endpoints it is working fine and While adding the third endpoint in the web.config it showing the following error

the following is my service added in the web.config

```
 <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="WCFCurd.WCFContactService">
        <endpoint address="contact" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFCurd.IWCFContact" />
        <endpoint address="Calc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFCurd.Ialc" />
        <endpoint address="addition" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFCurd.Addition" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <!--<baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:4072/WCFCurd"/>
          </baseAddresses>-->
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```

the error showing is

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   http://localhost:4072/WCFContactService.svc If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address. For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error URI: http://localhost:4072/WCFContactService.svc Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost:4072/WCFContactService.svc'. There was no endpoint
>   listening at http://localhost:4072/WCFContactService.svc that could
>   accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or
>   SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. The
>   remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.HTTP GET Error URI:
>   http://localhost:4072/WCFContactService.svc There was an error
>   downloading 'http://localhost:4072/WCFContactService.svc'. The request
>   failed with the error message:-- Service
>
> The service encountered an error.
>
> An ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value
>   is:System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call
>   to a WSDL export extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior

when the WCFContactService.scv run it will not , which showing th e above error when third endpoint is added

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aveTD.png)

Comment: what happens if you put the service URL in a browser?

Comment: URL is working. but the the third endpoint when we put it will not work in the application.

Comment: i drop an image in the question which page is not working

Comment: Check in the WCFContactService.svc ,repeated with  any same function name.

Comment: ya yes with same name ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example you can understand will help you  , try with this example

```
            public int SimpleExample(<interface> Example1)
            {
                return Example1.ID;
            }

            public int SimpleExample1(<interface> Example2)
            {
                return Example2.ID;
            }

            public int SimpleExample2(<interface> Example3)
            {
                return Example3.ID;
            }

            public int SimpleExample3(<interface> Example4)
            {
                return Example4.ID;
            }

            public int SimpleExample4(<interface> Example5)
            {
                return Example5.ID;
            }

            public int SimpleExample5(<interface> Example6)
            {
                return Example6.ID;
            }
            .......

            public int SimpleExampleN(<interface> ExampleN)
            {
                return ExampleN.ID;
            }
```

i din't find out any error in the above code in web.config. this may be occurred due to conflict of the function names or any interface name.